# How should I handle exceptions for API data requester?

Tags: c#, async-await

How should I handle this exception for API data requester?
The `Dostuff1,2,3` is 3 different functions that retrieves data from an API. This function is ran every minute. What I want to do is to catch the exception, but not stop the program, and rather let it retry on the next iteration. How should I solve this? I guess I shouldn't be using throw, but the code want me to return something.

```
public async Task<string> Dostuff1,2,3()
{
    try
    {
        using (HttpResponseMessage result = await _httpClient.GetAsync(Adrdess))
        using (HttpContent content = result.Content)
        {
            result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

        return data;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error");
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are several possibilities. Personally, I would not catch here. Just have it bubble up and handle retry in the caller.

Comment: That's not a question for us, but a (design) decision you have to make. When an exception occurs, you clearly have no string to return. So what do you want your code calling Dostuff* to do if there is no string to be returned?

Comment: Does this even compile? `data` should be out of scope for return, since it is local to the "using" block.

Comment: @Fildor I agree with what you are saying. I would like to retry if it should fail... Do you have any example how I can achieve this? And yeah, the string should be defined outside  the using. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If the return value is what concerns you, then you can return `null` or `new Task<string>(() => string.Empty)` since they basically mean that you have no data to return.

Now it depends if you have a project with clear requirements where you should always have a default value to return or some other data source if this one is not available, but if you just want the code to compile, you can have a simple `return null;` there.

Comment: What do you gain in returning null and swallowing the exception? 1. You'll have to add a null-check. 2. The caller cannot handle the exception. Lose-Lose-Situation :(

Comment: @Fildor I am not saying that he should be swallowing the exception, but depending on what he needs to achieve, he may want that (maybe with a logging mechanism). What I am doing is answering this: *I guess I shouldn't be using throw, but the code want me to return something.*

Comment: Well, fair enough. But since the code does not compile anyway, I am suspicious this is not the actual problem.

Comment: @meJustAndrew what if I'm returning a Task<List<Category>>? How should the exception return then?

Comment: @FredrikLinger depends on your requirements but you could return an empty list. Which only applies if it is not critical to make no distinction between a failed GET and "no elements".

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks duplicated to me. Instead of making 3 different functions, you should rather have one with arguments:

```
public async Task<string> GetStringFromAPIAsync( string resource )
{
        // check input
        if( string.IsNullOrWhitespace(resource) ) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(resource));

        using (HttpResponseMessage result = await _httpClient.GetAsync(resource))
        using (HttpContent content = result.Content)
        {
            result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return await content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 
            // Issue in your code: 'data' was out of scope for the return.
            // string data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        // return data; <- "data" is not visible here!
}
```

Mind that I got rid of all the exception handling here, since from my POV, it should be done by the caller, which also gives you more flexibility.

For example: you could write another function for retry like so:

```
public async Task<string> GetStringFromAPIWithRetryAsync(string resource, int maxRetry)
{
    // limit retry to 1 .. 100
    for( int retry = Math.Min(Math.Max(1,maxRetry),100); retry > 0 ; retry--){
       try{
          return await GetStringFromAPIAsync( resource );
       }
       catch(Exception ex){ // Actually, you'd only catch exceptions where a retry makes sense.
          if( retry > 0 ){
             Log.Warn("Attempt to get string from {0} failed! Reason: {1}", resource, ex.Message);
          }else{
             throw;
          }
       }
    }
}
```

If you just need a default in case of error, you could do this:

```
public async Task<string> GetStringFromAPIOrDefaultAsync(string resource, string defaultValue)
{
       string returnValue = defaultValue;
       try{
          returnValue = await GetStringFromAPIAsync( resource );
       }
       catch(Exception){ 
          Log.Warn("Attempt to get string from {0} failed! Reason: {1}", resource, ex.Message);
       }
       return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: in this case, where should I can the retry function ? Is there a way I can force a similar task exception to test? :)